Ardunio Board is undetectable in Ubuntu 24.04
I am trying to connect an Arduino board with Arduino IDE, no luck so far.
I am used to work with Arduino board, IDE via Ubuntu since 2021. It was working fine. After upgrading to 24.04 recently, I could not be able to connect to Arduino boards.
See the following result before I plugged the board.
hirantha@hirantha-home:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:3015 Lite-On Technology Corp. Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2c81 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. HD WebCam
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. iPhone 5/5C/5S/6/SE/7/8/X/XR
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0a12:4010 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0b0e:2465 GN Netcom Jabra Evolve 75
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0b0e:24c8 GN Netcom Jabra Link 380
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub             
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 17e9:4307 DisplayLink Universal TWIN HD Docking Station
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub

See the below result after I plugged the board.
hirantha@hirantha-home:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:3015 Lite-On Technology Corp. Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2c81 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. HD WebCam
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. iPhone 5/5C/5S/6/SE/7/8/X/XR
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0a12:4010 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0b0e:2465 GN Netcom Jabra Evolve 75
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0b0e:24c8 GN Netcom Jabra Link 380
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub             
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 17e9:4307 DisplayLink Universal TWIN HD Docking Station
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub

I cannot see any differences there. I tried removing brltty. No luck so far.

You filed to state if any software was installed to support this device. Also you need to verify with the maker of the device there product is compatible with Ubuntu 24.04 at this time or if it needs updates.

With earlier versions, I didn't have to install any specific software other than the Ardunio IDE, Once the board is plugged and selected the board, it automatically detected it. Currently I am using Arduino IDE version 2.3.2.
